# Replace the contencts of a column in an Access table with part of the existing contents

Tags: sql, ms-access, replace

I have a column in an Access table that contains a string of text, and I wish to replace the contents with only part of that string.

I've created a query that produces no errors, but when it runs it simply returns the whole of the `Novell Username` column, as opposed to actually altering the contest on the table.

```
UPDATE Novell SET [Novell Username] = REPLACE([Novell Username], [Novell Username], MID([Novell Username], INSTR([Novell Username], "."),  INSTR(INSTR([Novell Username], ".") + 1, [Novell Username], ".")))
```

So for example I have a table as follows -

> **Novell ID**    **Novell DN**                                 **Novell Username**
>   1                  .NameA.something.whetever    .NameA.something.whetever
>   1                  .NameB.something.whetever    .NameB.something.whetever
>   1                  .NameC.something.whetever    .NameC.something.whetever

And I need it to look like

> **Novell ID**    **Novell DN**                                 **Novell Username**
>   1                  .NameA.something.whetever    NameA
>   1                  .NameB.something.whetever    NameB
>   1                  .NameC.something.whetever    NameC

How can I amend my query to achieve the results I desire?

Comment: I love when someone gives a question with 3x answers a down vote but doesn't explain why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a small helper function:

```
Public Function NovellUsername(ByVal NovellDN As String) As String
    NovellUsername = Split(NovellDN, ".")(1)
End Function
```

In your query:

```
UPDATE Novell SET [Novell Username] = NovellUsername([Novell DN])
```

Comment: Bingo, thanks for the help.  Not sure why this works but my other tests didn't, but hey ho!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample data, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE Novell
    SET [Novell Username] = REPLACE(LEFT([Novell Username],
                                         INSTR(2, [Novell Username], ".")
                                        ), ".", "")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the exact same same result as I got fom my attempt.

Comment: Actually, something is wrong - I just tried `...SET[Novell Username] = "Test"...` and still nothing was changed.  Oh dear, investigating I shall go...

Answer (score 1):

Try this as replacement string:

```
mid([Novell Username],instr([Novell Username],".")+1, instr(2,[Novell Username], ".") -2)
```

what it does: find the first ".", find the second "." and copy the content in between and not include those "."s

this assumes all your fields are starting with "."s

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the exact same same result as I got fom my attempt.

Comment: Actually, something is wrong - I just tried `...SET[Novell Username] = "Test"...` and still nothing was changed.  Oh dear, investigating I shall go...